# Is there a way to write css selector that will return only n-th element?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Is there a way to write css selector that will return only n-th paragraph?
I wrote a code in Python with BeautifulSoup lib that looks like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer
import requests

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
print(response)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
print(soup)
```

Lets say that my response looks like this:

```
<div class = "article">
  <div class = "news">
    <p>text 1</p>
    <p>text 2</p>
    <p>text 3</p>
    <p>text 4</p>
    <p>text 5</p>
    <p>text 6</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to get only paragraphs so I did this:

```
news_links = soup.select("div.article div.news p") #returns list of p 
print(news_links)
```

And this is the result:

```
[<p>text 1</p>, <p>text 2</p>, <p>text 3</p>, <p>text 4</p>, <p>text 5</p>, <p>text 6</p>]
```

Is there a way to write a css selector that will return me only text 2 and text 3.
I want to write selector that will do that, I do not want to do

```
soup.select("div.article div.news p")[1:3]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah use `nth-child`:

- Select only first one: `soup.select("div.article div.news p:nth-child(1)")`
- Select only first and fourth: `soup.select("div.article div.news p:nth-child(1),p:nth-child(3)")`
- Select in a range 1-3 (Using a formula (an + b). a represents a cycle size, n is a counter (starts at 0), and b is an offset value): `soup.select("div.article div.news p:nth-child(-1n+3)")`

Comment: You are the best, Thanks my friend!
Do you think that you can help me with this:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64804060/accessing-all-elements-from-main-website-page-with-beautiful-soup

Comment: What if my elements are not only paragraphs, what If i have spans etc?
can I just do div.news:nth-child(1)?

Comment: Is it possible to access font element?
I have example that goes h1, font, p, p, p, font. I want to get only first font, and p,p,p and last font.

Comment: How should css selector look if i want to get from 3rd to last paragraph?

Answer (score 0):

for future help, here is my one.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
 
html_atag = """<html><body><div class = "article">
  <div class = "news">
    <p>text 1</p>
    <p>text 2</p>
    <p>text 3</p>
    <p>text 4</p>
    <p>text 5</p>
    <p>text 6</p>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_atag, 'lxml')
# select a div class news and the find require p tag.
p = soup.find("div",{'class':'news'}).findAll('p')[1:3] 

for i in p:
    print(i.text)
```